# get firestore server time from document or snapshot in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build 'time sensitive' application using Firebase firestore database. I got stuck on getting current timestamp from firestore. One of the solutions is to store ***firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()***  and then read it back again, but i would end up with at least one sequential write and one reads on every database read. I keep finding references to function GetReadTime() **here:**[stackoverflow answer suggesting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343038/how-to-write-a-query-get-firestore-current-server-time-using-firebase-java-admin)
**and here:** [firestore documentation?](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/firestore/v1beta1) which would solve my problem if it worked, but in my experience this function does not exist on document, nor querySnapshot.

I have tried:

```
function loadTasks() {

  db.collection("tasks_"+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  //.orderBy("clientSideFinish")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          renderTask(doc);
          console.log(doc.getReadTime());
          console.log(doc.GetReadTime());

        });
        console.log(querySnapshot.getReadTime());
        console.log(querySnapshot.GetReadTime());

    });
}
```

and all of console logs throw function does not exist exception.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve that requires you to fetch the server time?

Comment: I am trying to use only firestore time and avoid using clients time to avoid time manipulation. I have tasks which have start time stored as timestamp of creation, and duration and need to display it to the user with the count down.

Comment: You can't even trust the client to run your code correctly. The code could easily be modified to do whatever they want. If you don't trust the client, out the logic on the server, or make use of security rules if possible.